# Full-screen UIImageView aligning to bottom

Tags: objective-c, ios4

With the following code:

```
UIImageView *largeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];
[largeImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
largeImageView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

[viewController.view addSubview:largeImageView];
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

I would expect the image to be at the top of the View, not the bottom. I double-checked the origin x and y, and they are 0,0.

Here is a screenshot: http://cl.ly/8F3J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tommy for providing some thinking out loud and debugging help, I figured out what I was doing wrong. I changed around the order of operations and added the imageview as a subview *after* I pushed the viewcontroller on the nav stack. This fixed the issue as my view controller had it's new view from the nav controller.

Answer (score 0):

`largeImageView` is a subview of `viewController.view`, so its coordinates are relative to that of its superview. Probably you want something more like:

```
// the bounds of viewController.view contain its correct size, but
// have an origin of (0, 0)
largeImageView.frame = viewController.view.bounds;

[viewController.view addSubview:largeImageView];
```

What's probably happening at the minute is that you're getting a frame much larger than the view controller's view size, then the fact that `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` will be adding some space at the top and bottom of the view as necessary (assuming your image is proportionally wider than the target view) is pushing the image off the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the response and your explanation makes sense, however, I tried the code you provided and I'm seeing the same exact result.

Comment: Is it possible your view controller's view is ending up running off the bottom of the screen? What do you get if you NSLog viewController.view.frame.size.height?

Comment: Huh...interesting, it is outputting as 0. I am instantiating this view controller on the fly and I didn't give it a frame. Would this be the problem?

Comment: That's sort of weird, but I guess the results of UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit could be screwy in that case. Maybe do something like viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; so you can visually verify how large (and where) the view controller's view is?

Comment: By the looks of it, it almost seems as though its view is trying to be the full 480 in height and thus the image is centered in the middle.